# Can the preprocessor determine type

Tags: boost-preprocessor

If I have a preprocessor sequence such that

```
FOO((TEST, (BAR,BAZ)),
    (TEST2, 25, (BART, BAC)
   )
```

Is there any way to determine that in the first argument the second element is a tuple, while in the second argument the second element is a number?

1st arg, 2nd element = (BAR,BAZ)
2nd arg, 2nd element = 25

I'm using boost preprocessor. I understand that just standardizing the operations is easiest. However, I'm curious if it's possible for the preprocessor to determine types and return that information to me in a useful manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Boost.VMD](http://www.boost.org/libs/vmd/doc/html/index.html) (available since Boost 1.60) to achieve what you want. It has several macros that detect the type of the element (`BOOST_VMD_IS_TUPLE`, `BOOST_VMD_IS_SEQ`, `BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER`, ...). This library requires a modern enough compiler with support for variadic macros. [Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Cl6SnvnT53aO7x8j) is an example that prints the "type" of the second element of the tuple you pass:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/vmd/is_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/vmd/is_number.hpp>

#define IT_IS_A_TUPLE(TUPLE) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(TUPLE) " is a tuple"
#define IT_IS_NOT_A_TUPLE(ARG) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(ARG) " is something else"

#define IT_IS_A_NUMBER(NUMBER) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(NUMBER) " is a number"
#define IT_IS_NOT_A_NUMBER(ARG) BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_VMD_IS_TUPLE(ARG),IT_IS_A_TUPLE,IT_IS_NOT_A_TUPLE)(ARG)

#define DESCRIBE_ARGUMENT(ARG) BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER(ARG),IT_IS_A_NUMBER,IT_IS_NOT_A_NUMBER)(ARG)
#define FOO(TUPLE) DESCRIBE_ARGUMENT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1,TUPLE))

int main()
{
    std::cout << FOO((TEST, (BAR,BAZ))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << FOO((TEST2, 25, (BART, BAC))) << std::endl;
}
```

[Another example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BXgfL1z288HN20aP) using BOOST_VMD_GET_TYPE:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/vmd/get_type.hpp>


#define WHEN_ARG_IS_A_BOOST_VMD_TYPE_TUPLE(TUPLE) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(TUPLE) " is a tuple"

#define WHEN_ARG_IS_A_BOOST_VMD_TYPE_NUMBER(NUMBER) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(NUMBER) " is a number"

#define WHEN_ARG_IS_A_BOOST_VMD_TYPE_SEQ(SEQ) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(SEQ) " is a sequence"

#define DESCRIBE_ARGUMENT(ARG) BOOST_PP_EXPAND(BOOST_PP_CAT(WHEN_ARG_IS_A_,BOOST_VMD_GET_TYPE(ARG))(ARG))
#define FOO(TUPLE) DESCRIBE_ARGUMENT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1,TUPLE))

int main()
{
    std::cout << FOO((TEST, (BAR,BAZ))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << FOO((TEST2, 25, (BART, BAC))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << FOO((TEST3,(BAR)(BAZ),(BAR,BAZ))) << std::endl;
}
```